# PHP Extending A Class And Using Another Class With The Same Base

Tags: php, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I'm fairly new to PHP and am wondering if any problems would be caused by setting a class variable as a new instance of another class which in turn extends the same base class as the first class. Basically, if I have two classes, A and B, that both extend a Base class. Can I have a class, C, that extends A and also creates a new instance of B? I would like to do something like this:

```
// In its own file (BaseClass.php)
    class Base {
        public function log($message) {
            // Write $message to the log
        }
    }

// In its own file (ClassA.php)
    require_once("path/to/BaseClass.php");
    class A extends Base {
        public function test() {
            // Do some test
        }
    }

// In its own file (ClassB.php)
    require_once("path/to/BaseClass.php");
    class B extends Base {
        public function getData() {
            // Get data here
        }
    }

// In its own file (ClassC.php)
    require_once("path/to/ClassA.php");
    require_once("path/to/ClassB.php");
    class C extends A {
        protected $classB;

        public function run() {
            // Initialize an instance of class B
            $this->classB = new B;

            // Can call log() function of Base class because
            // class C extends class A which extends Base
            $this->log("Log Message");

            // Can also call log() function of Base class through
            // class B because class B extends Base
            $this->classB->log("Another Log Message");
        }
    }
    $classC = new C;
    $classC->run();
```

Will there be any conflicts in (from how I understand it) initialing the Base class twice within the same class C, and will it actually work to call the `log()` function of Base two different ways?

Comment: What is your real world need to do this? This smells of a poor implementation before a line is written

Comment: @Trent I have a class that requests data from my home router. I would like this Router class to extend my Base class that will include some "common" functions. Then I have another class--we'll call it "NetworkInfo"--that parses data retrieved from my router, and loads the data into database tables. I also have a class for managing the database things.  I would like the Database and Router classes to both extend the Base class. The NetworkInfo class extends the Router class, but then needs to be able to access functions of the Database class as well.

Comment: I highly recommend not continuing with the pattern you've thought up. This is a great article which helps understand SOLID software design principles, of which it sounds like your application is straying from https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design - I know this in no way answers your question; but it's the wrong question to ask and it wouldn't be helpful to encourage you to continuing designing software this way.

Comment: @Trent Thanks for the info and link. That article is definitely over my head. Going to take some time for me to wrap my brain around that. I'm still struggling to see the correct method of having a base class, say for logging, that all other classes use, without initializing multiple instances of the base class. Is it not possible to have a single base class that multiple processes use, even if parts of the processes reuse each other?

Comment: @Trent Thanks again for the push in a better direction. Been doing some research on the SOLID principle, specifically the Liskov Substitution Principle, and "Composition over Inheritance". These two articles have helped:
http://propelorm.org/blog/2011/03/03/don-t-copy-code-oh-and-inheritance-and-composition-are-bad-too.html
https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose
The first one was before traits in PHP, so I'm trying to keep that in mind. Anyway, looks like I still have a lot to learn.  Wish I could accept your comment(s) as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: easily solved - added my comment as an answer :) Glad it helped. Just a word of warning on Traits - use them wisely otherwise you'll run into resolution clashes on method names later down the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend not continuing with the pattern you've thought up.

This is a great article which helps understand SOLID software design principles, of which it sounds like your application is straying from https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

I know this in no way answers your question; but it's the wrong question to ask and it wouldn't be helpful to encourage you to continuing designing software this way.

Comment: If you're not going to answer the question then leave it as a comment

Comment: It was 5 years ago pal - and it was accepted as the correct answer as the OP learned from it: "Wish I could accept your comment(s) as the answer. Thanks again" But you know - good to see people are still lurking around for things to be annoyed about. Keep up the good work